# Array as property of one item inside a grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs, sencha-architect

I have a store connected to a model. One propertie of the model instance is an Array. I have set the type propertie to 'auto'. I have connected this store to a grid and this is where I have encountered trouble. How should I change the settings to display all the array instances inside the grid. Is this possible?
Now I only see [object:Object]. Please see screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The screen shot is not visible. Kindly give some link or upload again.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own [`renderer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer)  in grid columns configuration for colums in which you want to display array values.

For example, this renderer display all items from array separated with comma:

```
columns: [
    {
        ...
        renderer: function(value){
           return value.join(', ');
        }
        ...
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a renderer field to the column with a .toString() method on the value.  For example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    ...
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Title',  
            dataIndex: 'somearrayrecord'
            renderer: function(value) {
               return value.toString();
            }
        },
    ],
    ...
});
```

This will use javascript's array.toString() method, which will print out the values in your array.